# OS Supporting Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

If I were to setup IBM Bluemix local, what are the operating systems that can support the Bluemix software?

Been trying to look for answers in the internet but always end up frustrated because I can't find any answer. Even Bluemix site did not mention what is the OS requirement in setting up Bluemix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluemix Local is not a software product that you can install in your own operating system. It runs in your environment but it is still a subscription. 
The Bluemix Local install is only performed by IBM and it is an automated deployment of many virtual servers. It is also a managed offering, meaning that you don't have access to the operating system on those virtual machines. All the maintenance tasks are executed by IBM through a secure connection and a mechanism called Relay.
I guess you probably saw this link before, but the infrastructure requirements are described here: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/local/index.html#localinfra

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need Bluemix Support team to help you build the Bluemix local environment, Bluemix local is a cloud platform as a service that need to build on your infrastructure as a service.

Comment: You would need to work closely with IBM to deploy a Bluemix local environment, and the place to start is by making your request in an IBM support ticket - https://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport